# Как избавиться от пустых значений массива

Tags: c#, массивы

**Задача:**
написать алгоритм, позволяющий из массива чисел, сгенерировать два новых массива - первый содержит только отрицательные и второй только положительные.

**Вопрос:**
Вроде все написал все работает, вот только как избавиться от пустых значений массива. Я знаю что можно добавлять размер массива когда добавляется число в этот массив, но я не знаю как это написать.

**Алогитрм:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random ran = new Random();

        int[] main_mas = new int[6]; // Создаем главный массив

        for (int i = 0; i < main_mas.Length; i++) // Вводим переменные
            main_mas[i] = ran.Next(minValue: -20, maxValue: 20);

        int[] mas1 = new int[6]; // Создаем отриц. массив
        int[] mas2 = new int[6]; // Создаем плож. массив

        for (int i = 0; i < main_mas.Length; i++)
        {
            if (main_mas[i] < 0)
                mas1[i] = main_mas[i];
            else mas2[i] = main_mas[i];
        }  

        Console.WriteLine("Исход: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < main_mas.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(main_mas[i]);

        Console.WriteLine("Отриц: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < mas1.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(mas1[i]);

        Console.WriteLine("полож: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < mas2.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(mas2[i]);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Запуск алгоритма:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо Вашего кода

```
for (int i = 0; i < main_mas.Length; i++)
    {
        if (main_mas[i] < 0)
            mas1[i] = main_mas[i];
        else mas2[i] = main_mas[i];
    }
```

сделайте так:

```
int k=0, l=0; 

for (int i = 0; i < main_mas.Length; i++)
    {
        if (main_mas[i] < 0)
            mas1[k++] = main_mas[i];
        else mas2[l++] = main_mas[i];
    }
```

После выхода из цикла k и l содержат количество отрицательных и положительных элементов.

Надеюсь, Вы поняли свою ошибку. Если нет - спрашивайте.

Comment: Мне кажется, что ваш ответ не годится. Нужно же создать 2 новых массива без нулевых значений в них. А вы посчитали кол-во положит. и отрицательных и... что? Какой толк в этом? Или вы решили оставить возможность автору вопроса решать дальше, что делать с этим?

Comment: @Bulson Код не только считает, но и заполняет начало новых массивов без пробелов. Вот концы останутся пустыми, если длина с запасом была (заранее не посчитана)

Comment: @MBo это понятно, я про то, что результат все равно получается не тот, что нужен.

Comment: @Bulson естественно я не хочу "плодить халяву" и мне нужно, чтобы автор вопроса сам научился программировать, тем более судя по тексту вопроса это нормальный студент, которому нужно просто чуть подсказать, а дальше он сам поймет, что нужно делать.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов я понял, тогда +

Comment: @Bulson Ну самый критичный момент здесь исправлен. А дальше, насколько я понимаю, в шарпе нет ресайза массивов, нужно Copy делать? Или есть?

Comment: Ресайз есть, но им не рекомендуют злоупотреблять.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Спасибо за подсказку. Понял в чем дело.

Answer (score 0):

ты можешь использовать `List` для своей задачи
вот переделанный код:

```
var ran = new Random();

var mainArr = new int[6];

for (var i = 0; i < mainArr.Length; i++)
    mainArr[i] = ran.Next(minValue: -20, maxValue: 20);

var mas1 = new List<int>(6);
var mas2 = new List<int>(6);

foreach (var t in mainArr)
{
    if (t < 0) mas1.Add(t);
    else mas2.Add(t);
}

Console.WriteLine("Исход: \n");
foreach (var t in mainArr)
    Console.WriteLine(t);

Console.WriteLine("Отриц: \n");
foreach (var t in mas1)
    Console.WriteLine(t);

Console.WriteLine("полож: \n");
foreach (var t in mas2)
    Console.WriteLine(t);

Console.ReadKey();
```

реализация `List` имеет в себе массив (я указал длину начального)
он будет копироваться в массив большего размера если для элементов не хватит места
если будешь иметь дело с большими массивами, желательно оценить какими они будут чтобы не занимать лишнее место

Comment: С листом каждый, извините, дурак сможет. А вы используя только массивы напишите.:)

Comment: @Bulson Александр уже написал такой вариант